# Based on my experience, I've outlined the Kubernetes request flow. Could someone please add or highlight any points I might have overlooked?

Tags: kubernetes

Based on my experience, I've outlined the Kubernetes request flow. Could someone please add or highlight any points I might have overlooked?

When a user deploys an Nginx pod using kubectl create -f nginx.yaml, the request is processed by the kube-apiserver, which validates and stores the pod's configuration in the etcd database; the Kubernetes controllers within the kube-controller-manager then ensure the cluster's state matches the desired state, while the kube-scheduler assigns the pod to an appropriate node based on cluster resources and requirements, and finally, the kubelet on the assigned node interacts with the container runtime to start the pod, with kube-proxy managing networking aspects to ensure traffic can reach the pod via services' virtual IPs, maintaining the desired application state, high availability, and scalable deployments across the cluster.

kuberneties architecture flow